# How to initialize a hashmap in c?

Tags: c, hashmap

I need to initialize a hashmap in C. I have created structs for hashnode and hashmap which will be shown below, but I need to send it to a function

```
void hashmap_init(hashmap_t *hm, int table_size);
```

and I need to initialize the hash map 'hm' to have given size and item_count 0. Have to ensure that the 'table' field is initialized to an array of size 'table_size' and filled with NULLs.

```
typedef struct hashnode {  
char key[128];                
char val[128];                
struct hashnode *next;        
} hashnode_t;


typedef struct {  
int item_count;               
int table_size;               
hashnode_t **table;            
} hashmap_t;

#define HASHMAP_DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `malloc()` to allocate an array of `table_size` buckets.

```
void hashmap_init(hashmap_t *hm, int table_size) {
    hm->item_count = 0;
    hm->table_size = table_size;
    hm->table = malloc(table_size * sizeof *(hm->table));
    for (int i = 0; i < table_size; i++) {
        hm->table[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

If you need to remove the hash map, you reverse the allocations:

```
for (int i = 0; i < hm->table_size; i++) {
    free(hm->table[i]);
}
free(hm->table);
```

Comment: you didn't provide a way to delete those allocated objects. So you assume, the person who asked this question knows that this memory needs to be deleted

Comment: You are missing hm->table = NULL; in removing hash map. And technically, you are not removing hash map but entries under that.

Comment: `free(hm->table);` should be outside the for loop.

Comment: @Harveer Management of the memory for the `hashmap_t` variable is the responsibility of whoever called `hashmap_init`, it can't be done by the hashmap functions themselves.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I know. But you used **If you need to remove the hash map, you reverse the allocations:** statement which states that code under that is removing hash map. I am just pointing that.